# hiding a view in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a small problem.I have a view which should be set to hidden when the view loads is tried to add

```
[self.view setHidden:YES];
```

in viewWillAppear and the view is hiding but the Hiding of view is visible(it takes a split second to hide after the app is loaded).I need to hide the view without it visible.Help me ?

My full code in viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
@try {

    NSLog(@"\n\n--------------Mainview Controller------------\n");

    // Guided access mode call mainview in iOS7. It making issue in UI

    [getStartBox setHidden:NO];
    appDel.deviceModel=[self platformString];

    if([MainView checkRegistrationStatus])
    {
        NSLog(@"Already registered....");
        [main setGlobalValues];

        if ([appDel.configArray count]==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Load app sync page...");
            [self.view setHidden :YES];
           // [_mainView setHidden:YES];
            AppSync *sync=[[AppSync alloc]initWithNibName:@"AppSync" bundle:nil];
            sync.appSyncData = configureData;
            [self presentViewController:sync animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",appDel.logInStatus);

            if([appDel.logInStatus isEqualToString:@"false"])
            {
                [self.view setHidden :YES];
               // [_mainView setHidden:YES];
                NSLog(@"Load login view controller...");
                appDel.isEmergencyAlertOn=NO;     
                appDel.isRespondingToAlert=NO;

                LogInViewController *loginView=[[LogInViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self presentViewController:loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
            else if([appDel.logInStatus isEqualToString:@"true"])
            {
                NSLog(@"Load alert screen");

                [self.view setHidden :YES];
               // [_mainView setHidden:YES];
                    AlertScreen *alert=[[AlertScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"AlertScreen" bundle:nil];
                    alert.alertData=notificationData;
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        appDel.domainName=nil;
        // Version number reffered in settings page. The log enabled one should be in same format (Ex Version 1.0.53(log enabled))

        versionLabel.text=@"Version 1.3(log enabled)";//(log enabled)
        appDel.appVersion=versionLabel.text;
        //self.view.layer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]CGImage];
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
        ConfigureButton.hidden=NO;
     }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

     [[WriteLogger getWriteLogger] writeLog:moduleName sourceClass:self.nibName methodName:@"viewDidAppear" errorMsg:exception];
}
```

Comment: Have you trid it in ViewWillAppear?

Comment: better way is to put this in viewDidLoad

Comment: Sorry for the trouble guys but i solved the problem myself.I called vieDidAppear in viewWillApear and it worked

Comment: it's not a good practise to call viewDidAppear in viewWillAppear, why not put the code inside viewDidLoad

Comment: yes @Shadowfiend is right that is poor programming.

Comment: Then what i should do @Shadowfiend to solve my problem.Suggest me a better solution

Comment: adding the code as you suggested did not help same problem @MohitPopat

Comment: why not just put the view.hidden = YES in viewDidLoad? @vishnuvarthan

Comment: Then how will i show that for the first time.even then it will be hidden.

Comment: No problem anyway i initially set the views hidden and used user defaults .